# How to bypass preflight check while setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?

Tags: python, ajax, http, flask, cors

I have a flask app running on 127.0.0.1:5000 and another website running on 127.0.0.1:8000. The website has js function making a post request to the flask app, trying to post some dictionary data to the flask app. In the js function i'm using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',},
    data: dict,
});
```

In the flask app:

```
@app.route('/',methods=['POST'])
def hello_world():
    ok = request.get_json()
    print(ok['id'])
    return '', 200
```

Initially in the ajax call, i didn't put any headers. But it prompted me "Cross-Origin Request Blocked". Then I add the header and the request apparently turns into an OPTIONS request, which after googling, suggests pre-flight check. How can I avoid the check? Or why does this check returns a 200 code and the actual post request does not get through? Please give me some help! I am stuck on this for hours. Thanks!
(p.s. i have tried installing `flask_cors` library and applied it in the flask app but it also does not work)

Comment: flask_cors is your answer .... keep chasing that

Answer (score 0):

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is a *response* header - you don't pass it in your request (from the website JS) - you pass it in the response from your Flask app.

If you pass it in the request, it does nothing, EXCEPT make the browser send a preflight OPTIONS request, since it's not a basic request header.

So.

1. Remove the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` request header from your JS
2. Add the `Access-Control-Allow-Options: *` response header to your Flask app (I'm not sure how you add response headers in Flask)